# How to send parameters to python in eclipse on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, python

Java code:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter(); 

interpreter.execfile("/home/parallels/Desktop/EE3P2/workspace2014/ConceptNetSimilarity/src/ConceptNetSimilarity.py");

PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("similar");

PyObject result = someFunc.__call__(new PyString("cat dog"));

System.out.println((String) result.__tojava__(String.class));
```

---

Python:

```
import divisi2 

assoc = divisi2.network.conceptnet_assoc('en')

U, S, _ = assoc.svd(k=100)

spread = divisi2.reconstruct_activation(U, S)

def similar(str1,str2):

    return spread.entry_named(str1,str2)
```

---

Result:

```
Traceback (innermost last):

  File "/home/parallels/Desktop/EE3P2/workspace2014/ConceptNetSimilarity/src/ConceptNetSimilarity.py", line 1, in ?

ImportError: no module named divisi2
```

---

What should I do next? I don't know how to set path of divisi2. I can get right result in terminal, but I can't in eclipse. Thank you!

Comment: divisi2 is a module that calculates the semantic similarity score between two words. I send two words from Java to Python and hope to get result from Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for **divisi2** module into ubuntu repositories and didn't find it. So, I'm assuming you don't got **divisi2** by installing the module, and that's why the module isn't in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Said that try adding manually the module to the `PYTHONPATH`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, path_to_divisi2_parent_folder)
import divisi2 

assoc = divisi2.network.conceptnet_assoc('en')

U, S, _ = assoc.svd(k=100)

spread = divisi2.reconstruct_activation(U, S)

def similar(str1,str2):

    return spread.entry_named(str1,str2)
```

In the code above, **path_to_divisi2_parent_folder** is the path to the folder containing the module. If the module part of a package(lets call it `some_package`), I recommend you insert the package's parent folder to the path instead. And use the module like this:

```
from some_package import divisi2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I add 'sys' as your advice and divisi2 is read. But it said there is an invaild syntax in one of divisi2's file. I have no idea, so I try another meaning. Would you mind help me have a look at it? Thank you. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157108/how-to-send-arguments-to-python-in-java)